# Question about the definition of axisymmetric vector fields

Tags: vector-fields, symmetry, cylindrical-coordinates

i just started to study axisymmetric vector fields. In the definition it says a vector field $V$ in cylindrical coordinates $V(\rho,\varphi,z)$ is axisymmetric if it does not depend on the angular, i.e. we actually have $V(\rho,z)$. Since we have the standard basis $e_{\rho}=(\cos(\varphi),\sin(\varphi),0)$, $e_{\varphi}=(-\sin(\varphi),\cos(\varphi),0)$ and $e_z=(0,0,1)$,
\begin{align}
V=V_{\rho} e_{\rho}+ V_{\varphi}e_{\varphi}+V_z e_z
\end{align}
So $V$ does in general depend on the angular $\varphi$. Can somebody resolve my confusion?

Comment: They mean it is sysmmetric w.r.t. to a rotation around the $z$-axis if and only if its components $V_\rho,V_\varphi,V_z$ do not depend on $\varphi$. Here is a terrific visualization tool from [Oregon State University](https://books.physics.oregonstate.edu/GSF/pcurlggb.html).

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for your visualization. It makes sense. I didn't really find any book on a clear definition. I only found some papers where they use different definitions. For example https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-020-02050-0. On page 3 they state $u=u(t,r,z)$ and $u=u_r e_{\rho}+ u_z e_z$. This is also why I was confused. In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579766/how-to-determine-if-a-3-d-velocity-flow-is-axisymmetric it looks more like what you suggested... but I still don't get if there is any difference between the definitions or am I just stupid?

Comment: In my own learning about cylindrical coordinates I found it very convenient to describe the basis vectors not like you do (or perhaps those other links) but as partial derivatives $\partial_\rho,\frac{1}{r}\partial_\varphi,\partial_z$ which is what modern differential geometers do. This helped a lot to formulate [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4652440/949989) for example which quickly led to the known correct result. If you apply this to, say, the vector field $V=(x,y,0)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ you will quickly see that it is axisymmetric and how it looks like in cylindrical coordinates